# Webmin "allow" parameter for all Internet IP's

Tags: centos5, remote-access

Is it possible to allow connections to Webmin from any Internet ip?

I tried

```
allow=127.0.0.1 0.0.0.0/32
```

But still blocking my remote access over Internet.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `0.0.0.0/0`?

Comment: Yup, I put the wrong CIDR in the file. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your IPTables to ensure the port is open?

Try the following:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT
iptables save
iptables restart
```

Comment: This wasn't my first question, but solved the problem of turning iptables off. Thx!